# NIMH Battery excedes charge limit when plugged into Tenergy Charger?

Tags: batteries

I recently purchased a NIMH Battery (5000MAH, 7.2V) and when I plugged it into my Tenergy Battery Charger I set the charge rate to 5amps. After watching it for several minutes the "voltage" jumped to around 8volts. Did I set it to the correct amps? Why did it exceed its apparent voltage limit?

Sorry, I'm still new to this, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's fine.** If your cells are rated for a nominal 7.2 volts that means it's 7.2/1.2=6 cells. When charging NiMH's especially when you're charging them fast, the voltage can get up pretty high relative to the nominal voltage.

[image]

As you can see from the picture the charging voltage can get up to something around 1.5V per cell. With your battery pack that means you can go up to 1.5*6 or 9 volts before you're going to see the end of the charging cycle. If it gets up to a voltage much higher than that, then you should start getting worried.

NiMH's aren't charged with a constant voltage, they're charged with a constant current and then they're either cutoff with a timer (poor), a negative delta-V (ok), or a slight temperature rise (better). So don't be surprised if voltage is a secondary concern when you see the chargers doing what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not.  I have several "professional-class" chargers and they all show voltage much higher than the rated pack voltage while charging.

That said: I *really* don't like charging NiMh or NiCd batteries at a rate higher than about C/2 (or lower).  Your batteries will thank you by giving you longer service life.

Comment: C/2 to C/3 is good. If you go much less than C/3 it makes it harder to terminate properly.